# Get Serilog to append its first log file with _001

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

Is it possible to configure Serilog so that the default log file is appended with _001 and if the file limit is reached, that subsequent files are appended with _002, _003 etc.

This is in the context of a ASP.NET Core application.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible to express this given how the config API has worked since very early days, and, there's no obvious way you make it possible without making the API messy and/or risking breaking people's configs...

As [Nick replied](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/40#issuecomment-380982122) to [my suggestion](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/40#issuecomment-380862153)

> makes sense - the only drawback is that we would risk breaking existing apps by making it the default, and yet it seems too minor to warrant a new top-level configuration option.